# Python won't Receive UDP Packets(Non Broadcast)

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I'm Writing a script in python2.7 on a windows XP machine. The machine is connected to multiple networks using different network cards. I have already posted a question that relates to this issue but does not directly address it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976551/python-udp-sockets-with-multiple-interfaces)

I have a server that is sending "status data" via UDP at ~1 sec intervals

The Servers Ip: **10.42.40.34**
My Machines IP: **10.31.9.0**

The Card I'm using: **Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter**

I can observer the "Servers" packets (via wireshark) being sent to "My Machine".

```
2995    19.592120   10.42.40.34 10.31.9.0   UDP 455 000000007e4e9ca700000000040404000301000000000100... Source port: 62415  Destination port: 62415
3012    19.688119   10.42.40.34 10.31.9.0   UDP 455 000000007e4e9ca700000000040404000301000000000100... Source port: 62415  Destination port: 62415
```

The socket is created with no problems:

```
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

However when I bind a socket to the interface:

```
self.sock.bind(('10.31.9.0', 62415))
```

Then use(with no timeout set):

```
reply, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(65535)
```

to receive, my script just waits at the `recvfrom()` method call. which implies to me that it isn't receiving packets. Even though I verified that it is via Wireshark.

I'm really banging my head against the wall, any help would be much apreciated...

Bellow is the full "status" packet pulled from wireshark, I'm thinking maybe some of the header info might be bad and that's why python is ignoring it... IDK

```
0000   03 00 00 00 81 b5 02 00 00 2a 28 20 08 00 45 00  .........*( ..E.
0010   01 b8 1b 2b 40 00 01 11 17 a0 0a 2a 28 22 0a 1f  ...+@......*("..
0020   09 00 f3 cf f3 cf 01 a4 00 00 00 00 00 00 7e 4e  ..............~N
0030   9c a7 00 00 00 00 04 04 04 00 03 01 00 00 00 00  ................
0040   01 00 3e 99 99 9a 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ..>.............
0050   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3e 8c e7 04 3e 9c  ..........>...>.
0060   43 2d bf 17 5f 6e bf 17 5f 6e 00 00 00 00 00 00  C-.._n.._n......
0070   00 00 03 01 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 04 00 00 04 04  ................
0080   00 00 04 04 00 00 04 04 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00  ................
0090   00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00  .............@..
00a0   00 00 40 90 00 00 40 86 4c cb 40 90 00 00 40 86  ..@...@.L.@...@.
00b0   4c cb bf 09 09 21 40 6a 57 4e 40 6a 57 4e 3f dc  L....!@jWN@jWN?.
00c0   b1 4e 3f dc b1 4e bf f7 fd 4e bf f7 fd 4e 3e 80  .N?..N...N...N>.
00d0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00e0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00f0   00 0f 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ee ee 00 00 00  ................
0100   00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0110   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0120   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0130   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0140   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0150   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0160   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0170   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0180   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0190   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
01a0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
01b0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
01c0   00 00 79 c7 42 05 56                             ..y.B.V
```

Comment: Did you create the socket with `socket.AF_INET` and `socket.SOCK_DGRAM`?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question to reflect this...

Comment: And maybe you could try changing the buffer from `65535` to `1` to verify that it's nothing strange going on here (maybe it's waiting for the full buffer to fill up)

Comment: No, just tried, Thats not it... I originally had it as 1024 and it wasn't working. I read somewhere that 65535 is the theoretical maximum for UDP packets... but im not sure if it is, works perfectly fine on other applications that i've written

Comment: Are you running Linux? Have you verified using `netstat` that your script really is listening on the expected address and port? With `netstat -lp` (as root) you should see something like: `udp        0      0 10.31.9.0:62415  *:*                                 3210/python`

Comment: the skript is running on windows XP, However using the Command "netstat -a -v -n -o -p udp" ... I can verify that there is indeed an a open UDP socket on my expected address and port.

Comment: Could it be a firewall (Windows built-in?) blocking the packets? But maybe they shouldn't be visible in Wireshark if they're getting blocked?

Comment: I thought the same thing, But checked settings and there is no firewall active... ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the Packets that my "server" was sending where not IP kosher. so they where getting rejected at the network and transport layers. Solution was to not use python socket class, but instead communicate directly to OSI-L2 using [winpcap](https://www.winpcap.org/) and ctypes